# How to produce increasing quarter, month and year output in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, window-functions

| Year | Month | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | 1 |
| 2012 | 2 | 1 |
| 2012 | 3 | 1 |
| 2012 | 4 | 2 |
| 2012 | 5 | 2 |
| 2012 | 6 | 2 |
| 2012 | 7 | 3 |
| 2012 | 8 | 3 |
| 2012 | 9 | 3 |
| 2012 | 10 | 4 |
| 2012 | 11 | 4 |
| 2012 | 12 | 4 |
| 2013 | 1 | 5 |
| 2013 | 2 | 5 |
| 2013 | 3 | 5 |
| 2013 | 4 | 6 |
| 2013 | 5 | 6 |
| 2013 | 6 | 6 |
| 2013 | 7 | 7 |
| 2013 | 8 | 7 |
| 2013 | 9 | 7 |
| 2013 | 10 | 8 |
| 2013 | 11 | 8 |
| 2013 | 12 | 8 |

Explanation:
Year column increments by 1 after every 12 rows.
Month column goes till 12 and then resets.
Quarter column increments by 1 after every 3 rows but does not reset after year

Comment: MySql <> Sql Server. Exactly *what* is your question?

Comment: Sorry, removed the tag. I want to generate a similar output as above table.

Comment: Have a Google for *calendar table*

Comment: @Stu Don't want a calendar table. Want a query which generates similar kind of output.

Comment: Like the SQL that **generates** a *Calender Table*.

Comment: Calendar tables don't generally have quarters like above. In the above output, quarters aren't getting reset after the year changes

Comment: Yes they can; *you* change the SQL that creates the calendar table to your bespoke needs.

Comment: @Larnu At least have a look at the Quarter column and check that they aren't resetting after every year. That's the kind of output I require. It's kind of an interview question which I am not able to figure out. It'd be helpful if you at least give me a hint on how to achieve it.

Comment: Hint: `(ROW_NUMBER() -1)/ 3 + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a tally table to get row numbers and use modulo (%) and integer division to derive the numbers

```
with cteTally as (
    SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY NAME) -1 as MonthNumber 
    FROM sys.objects 
)
SELECT 
    CEILING(MonthNumber / 12) + 2012 as CalYear
    , (MonthNumber % 12) + 1 as CalMonth
    , 1 + (MonthNumber / 3) as CalQuarter
FROM cteTally as T
```

| CalYear | CalMonth | CalQuarter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012 | 1 | 1 |
| 2012 | 2 | 1 |
| 2012 | 3 | 1 |
| 2012 | 4 | 2 |
| 2012 | 5 | 2 |
| 2012 | 6 | 2 |
| 2012 | 7 | 3 |
| 2012 | 8 | 3 |
| 2012 | 9 | 3 |
| 2012 | 10 | 4 |
| 2012 | 11 | 4 |
| 2012 | 12 | 4 |
| 2013 | 1 | 5 |
| 2013 | 2 | 5 |
| 2013 | 3 | 5 |
| 2013 | 4 | 6 |
| 2013 | 5 | 6 |
| 2013 | 6 | 6 |
| 2013 | 7 | 7 |
| 2013 | 8 | 7 |
| 2013 | 9 | 7 |
| 2013 | 10 | 8 |
| 2013 | 11 | 8 |
| 2013 | 12 | 8 |